# (SSRS) SQL Reports Web Service vs Report Viewer vs SQL Report Front End

Tags: reporting-services

We are planning to use SQL Reports in our company and we are currently evaluating the ways to expose the reports to end users. Should we use a reporting web service and then render the reports through a .NET Application? Should we use a report viewer or should we expose the SQL GUI to the users? What are the pros and cons of these over each other? Could anyone please help? I couldn't find any information anywhere for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest is to use the Report Manager website that is enabled by default with an SSRS installation it's very quick and easy to get running and the security/ snapshot(cache) / subscription (email etc) options are easy to configure on a per site /per folder /per report basis. It's drawbacks are:

1. It's ugly - although if you are good with CSS it is possible to mess
   with it, but I wouldn't. Newer versions e.g. 2008R2 and 2012 are less ugly
2. It has an ugly URL - although you could use a DNS alias to get
   around that
3. It doesn't let you control how parameter drop-downs and other
   objects appear on the page, but that's minor

I usually use Sharepoint (MOSS not WSS) (if the company has that) with the report viewer web-part. It doesn't require any special Sharepoint SSRS integrated mode - you can read about that but it's that's not a path I recommend taking.

The reports then appear to be embedded within the company's existing intranet site which looks professional IMO. Powerview for sharepoint is also a good option (or performance point in older versions of Sharepoint)

I would definitely NOT go down the road of webservice, that would entail a huge amount of unecessary programming. If you have a lot of spare .NET developers around I still wouldn't do that.

Rather to use the report viewer object in Visual Studio to display a report in an .NET web application. Designing reports using the BIDS (2008R2 and earlier) or SSDT (2012) is much easier than programming, particularly if you've used other reporting tools such as crystal reports or even Access. Using that report viewer object is a much better option than rolling your own.

I've written my response in order of easiness and work required. Hope that is helpful.

Comment: but doesn't that mean if you go with report manager then you will have to individually give access to each user to a particular role rather than using impersonation in .NET application?

Comment: Assuming you're a Microsoft shop and use Active Directory (or even LDAP) then you can use domain groups for access. You apply roles to those groups. As people come and go from the organisation you apply the groups to them as appropriate and then they have access to the appropriate report folders. My sysadmin colleagues maintain user templates in their AD to make that easy, but I don't know much about that side of things. 

Report manager has its own impersonation options that you can apply to DB connection objects. It makes it easy to use windows authentication everywhere as MS intended.